# React props not working when map() function on json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-props

I'm trying to render information from a json file that I made to show on a page. I have used bootstrap for formatting the cards but when I try it without the bootstrap formatting it still doesn't work. Any ideas for what it is missing?

My json file:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "projectname": "Having fun",
        "description": "Having fun that is the project",
        "image":"../assets/images/havingfun.png"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "projectname": "Weather App",
        "description": "Weather app that is the project",
        "image":"../assets/images/weather.png" 
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "projectname": "Daily Planner",
        "description": "Daily planner is the project",
        "image": "../assets/images/planner.png"
      
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "projectname": "Code Quiz",
        "description": "Multiple Choice Quiz is the project",
        "image": "../assets/images/MCQ.png"
            
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 5,
        "projectname": "Password Generator",
        "description": "Password generator that is the project",
        "image": "../assets/images/passwordgenerator.png" 
      
    },
    {
        "id" : 6,
        "projectname": "Horiseon",
        "description": "Horiseon that is the project",
        "image": "../assets/images/horiseon.png" 
        
    }
]
```

Projects.js that the json file is being imported to:

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import ProjectCards from '../jsonfiles/projects.json';


function ProjectCard(props) {
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>3
        <Card.Img variant="top" alt={props.projectname} src={props.image} />
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{props.projectname}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>{props.description}</Card.Text>
            <button className="deployedURL">Deployed Site{props.deployedURL}</button>
            <button className="githubURL">Github{props.githubUrl}</button>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
}

function Projects() {
    return (
        <div className="projectsAll">
            <div className="projectsTitle">
                <h1>Projects</h1>
                <p>Here are a few of the projects that have been create based on the client's requirements and design ideas</p>
            </div>
            <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-4">
                {Array.from({ length: 6 }).map((_, idx) => (
                    <Col>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col sm={6} className='softwareUsed'>
                                        <h1>HTML</h1>
                                        <p></p>
                                        <hr></hr>
                                        <h1>CSS</h1>
                                        <p></p>
                                        <hr></hr>
                                        <h1>JavaScript</h1>
                                        <p></p>
                                        <hr></hr>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} className='projectMiniCard'>
                                        {ProjectCards.map((project)=> (
                                            <ProjectCard
                                            projectname={project.projectname}
                                            image={project.image}
                                            description={project.description}
                                            />
                                        ))}
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </div >
    )
}
```

From my app.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from './pages/Header';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';
import About from './pages/AboutMe';
import Projects from './pages/Projects';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
         <Header /> 
         <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path="/aboutme" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
          <Route path="/contactme" element={<Contact />} />
         </Routes>
    </Router>
    
  )
}

export default App;
```

Wanting information from json file to show on the webpage.

Comment: Json file information is showing but now it is showing all of the arrays on each card, rather than 1 array on each card? any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `ProjectCard` component is not returning anything. It should return your jsx.

The code should be:

```
function ProjectCard(props) {
    return (
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>3
            <Card.Img variant="top" alt={props.projectname} src={props.image} />
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{props.projectname}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>{props.description}</Card.Text>
                <button className="deployedURL">Deployed Site{props.deployedURL}</button>
                <button className="githubURL">Github{props.githubUrl}</button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Comment: Also, you should either add an `onClick` to your buttons with `window.open` or change your buttons to an `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks but I now have all the info from the json file showing on each card rather than just the one card for each array. Would I have to map something else to achieve this?

Comment: You have mapped on an array of length 6. SO, what's happening is all the projects are being rendered for each element in the array, i.e 6 times.

I would be better if you can give more info on the output you want. By "card"you mean the parent card or the projectCard?

Comment: As in, I have 6 card templates using bootstrap and I want each of the array items from json file to render to each bootstrap card. I'm unsure how to overcome the map function that is rendering the 6 bootstrap cards.

Comment: Well in that case you shouldn't map an array of length 6. You should just map your json array directly. 

What map does is basically render the whole list. If you map your json list inside a map of Array of size 6, it will basically be 6 X 6 = 36 cards which you do not want. Just do a simple json map and render your bootstrap card.

Comment: Relpace `{Array.from({ length: 6 }).map` with `{ProjectCards.map`

Answer (score 0):

`ProjectCard` function is not returning anything. Also don't forget to add the key prop when iterating. And take a look at this typo in the end of line `<Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>3`